# Where can I find Delphi´s component editor for TPopupMenu and TMenuItem?

Tags: delphi, components

I need to write custom component editors for Delphi's TPopupMenu and TMenuItem descendent controls.

Finding the native editors will make my work a lot easier, but after inspecting the folder "\source\Property Editors", I was unable to find files that seems to be the right ones for them.

Any help will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find Delphi's component editor for `TPopupMenu` and `TMenuItem`?

You can't. The source code for these component editors is not published.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to make the native menu designer shows the TMenuItem descendent on object inspector?